# Python: WebKit.WebView: how to reload on error?

Tags: python, webview, gtk, webkit, gtk3

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704990/wxpython-webview-how-to-reload-on-error), which was **answered**. I'm trying exactly the same, but with `WebKit.WebView` with `GTK` and I'm stuck at the same part.

**Goal:** Load another URL if the first isn't reachable.

```
import gi, time
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit

browser = WebKit.WebView()
browser.load_uri('http://this-domain-does-not-exist.tld')

def load_error(webview, event, url, error):
  webview.load_uri('http://google.com') # not working

browser.connect('load-error', load_error)

win = Gtk.Window()
win.add(browser)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason commands that are run within the error callback are ignored. A fix is to add the fallback uri loading after all other events are processed. Like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit, GLib

....

def load_error(webview, event, url, error):
    GLib.idle_add(webview.load_uri, 'http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by moving to WebKit2 and returning `True` in the callback. It's possible that only the return works for WebKit as well but I don't have that available to test. Modified code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

browser = WebKit2.WebView()
browser.load_uri('http://this-domain-does-not-exist.tld')

def load_failed(webview, event, url, error):
    webview.load_uri('http://google.com')
    return True

browser.connect('load-failed', load_failed)  # Changed from load-error

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.add(browser)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

From the [documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/WebKit2-4.0/classes/WebView.html#WebKit2.WebView.signals.load_failed):

> Returns: True to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event. False to
>   propagate the event further.